# SHOW SLAVE STATUS in stored procedure

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, cursor, replication

I'm fairly new to mysql stored procedures and I need to be able to access the results of SHOW SLAVE STATUS from within the procedure. I searched the web but can't seem to be able to find it. This is the kind of thing I've been trying:

```
    CREATE PROCEDURE test()
BEGIN
 DECLARE a VARCHAR(1000);
 DECLARE cur1 CURSOR FOR SHOW SLAVE STATUS;
 DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET done = TRUE;

 OPEN cur1;

 read_loop: LOOP
  FETCH cur1 INTO a;
  IF done THEN
   LEAVE read_loop;
  END IF;
 END LOOP;

 SELECT a;

 CLOSE cur1;
END;
```

This fails with the following:

```
ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'SHOW SLAVE STATUS;
 DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET done = TRUE;
```

If there is another way to do this (not using a cursor maybe, as there is only one row returned) that would be great.

Answer (score 2):

Just in case someone else has this issue.

I found a dirty way around it. I don't get all the info I need but it's a start.

`information_schema.processlist` (or `SHOW PROCESSLIST`) has the slave process which I can use in a stored procedure:

```
+-----+-------------+---------------------+---------+---------+-------+-----------------------------------------------------------------------+------------------+
| Id  | User        | Host                | db      | Command | Time  | State                                                                 | Info             |
+-----+-------------+---------------------+---------+---------+-------+-----------------------------------------------------------------------+------------------+
|   1 | system user |                     | NULL    | Connect | 75212 | Waiting for master to send event                                      | NULL             |
|   2 | system user |                     | NULL    | Connect |  2158 | Has read all relay log; waiting for the slave I/O thread to update it | NULL             |
+-----+-------------+---------------------+---------+---------+-------+-----------------------------------------------------------------------+------------------+
```